# SQL Server - How to make an INTERSECT select optional?

Tags: sql-server, intersect, advanced-search

I'm working on an advanced search sproc and would like to know if it is possible for a portion of my select to be included or not based on a parameter.  I could use an IF ELSE on my parameter, but I already have one for another parameter, and that seems like a lot of code duplication.

-- My advanced search function allows a user to specify various parameters.  The basic search can be EXACT or not (contains vs freetext - first if), and other parameters (AND) can be specified.  Specific keywords can also be selected as well (intersect).

My issue is that when @Keywords is null, I don't want to include the final INTERSECT SELECT ... portion of the code at the bottom of my example. Is there a quick way to do this without adding another IF ELSE in the top and bottom queries?  Let me know if you need more detailed information.

```
declare @SearchTerms nvarchar(4000)
declare @GalleryId int
declare @Keywords nvarchar(4000)
declare @ExactWord int
declare @BeginDateUpload datetime
declare @EndDateUpload datetime 
declare @BeginDateTaken datetime
declare @EndDateTaken datetime 
declare @MinFileSize int
declare @MaxFileSize int 
declare @AlbumType bit 
declare @ImageType int 
declare @AudioType int 
declare @OtherType int 
declare @VideoType int 

set @SearchTerms = 'tulips'
set @GalleryId = 1
set @Keywords = null -- 'st-jean'
set @ExactWord = null
set @BeginDateUpload  = null
set @EndDateUpload  = null 
set @BeginDateTaken  = null
set @EndDateTaken  = null 
set @MinFileSize  = null
set @MaxFileSize  = null 
set @AlbumType  = 1 
set @ImageType  = 1 
set @AudioType  = 1 
set @OtherType  = 1 
set @VideoType  = 1
IF ISNULL(@ExactWord, 0) = 1
    BEGIN
            [... snip ...]
    END
ELSE
  select t1.* from (    
    SELECT   'm' as objType, m.MediaObjectId  
    FROM gs_mediaObjectMetadata md 
         INNER JOIN dbo.[gs_MediaObject] m
         ON md.FKMediaObjectId = m.MediaObjectId
        INNER JOIN  dbo.[gs_Album] a
         ON a.AlbumId = m.FKAlbumId 
         WHERE FREETEXT (value, @SearchTerms) 
        AND  a.FKGalleryId = @GalleryId
        AND (m.DateAdded >= ISNULL(@BeginDateUpload, m.DateAdded))
        AND (m.DateAdded <= ISNULL(@EndDateUpload, m.DateAdded))
        AND (m.DateTaken is NULL OR m.DateTaken >= ISNULL(@BeginDateTaken, m.DateTaken))
        AND (m.DateTaken is NULL OR m.DateTaken <= ISNULL(@EndDateTaken, m.DateTaken))
        AND (m.OriginalSizeKB >= ISNULL(@MinFileSize, m.OriginalSizeKB))
        AND (m.OriginalSizeKB <= ISNULL(@MaxFileSize, m.OriginalSizeKB))
        AND((m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@ImageType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@AudioType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@VideoType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@OtherType, 0)))



union

        SELECT 'm' as objType, m.MediaObjectId  
 FROM dbo.[gs_MediaObject] m
        INNER JOIN  dbo.[gs_Album] a
         ON a.AlbumId = m.FKAlbumId 
         WHERE FREETEXT ((m.Title, OriginalFilename), @SearchTerms) 
        AND  a.FKGalleryId = @GalleryId
        AND (m.DateAdded >= ISNULL(@BeginDateUpload, m.DateAdded))
        AND (m.DateAdded <= ISNULL(@EndDateUpload, m.DateAdded))
        AND (m.DateTaken is NULL OR m.DateTaken >= ISNULL(@BeginDateTaken, m.DateTaken))
        AND (m.DateTaken is NULL OR m.DateTaken <= ISNULL(@EndDateTaken, m.DateTaken))
        AND (m.OriginalSizeKB >= ISNULL(@MinFileSize, m.OriginalSizeKB))
        AND (m.OriginalSizeKB <= ISNULL(@MaxFileSize, m.OriginalSizeKB))
        AND((m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@ImageType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@AudioType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@VideoType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@OtherType, 0)))
    )   t1
--IF @Keywords != null -- conditional intersect
 intersect

        SELECT 'm' as objType, m.MediaObjectId  
 FROM dbo.[gs_MediaObject] m
        INNER JOIN  dbo.[gs_Album] a
         ON a.AlbumId = m.FKAlbumId 
        left join dbo.gs_MediaObjectMetadata md
        on m.MediaObjectId = md.FKMediaObjectId
         WHERE FREETEXT ((m.Title, OriginalFilename), @SearchTerms) 
        AND  a.FKGalleryId = @GalleryId
        AND (m.DateAdded >= ISNULL(@BeginDateUpload, m.DateAdded))
        AND (m.DateAdded <= ISNULL(@EndDateUpload, m.DateAdded))
        AND (m.DateTaken is NULL OR m.DateTaken >= ISNULL(@BeginDateTaken, m.DateTaken))
        AND (m.DateTaken is NULL OR m.DateTaken <= ISNULL(@EndDateTaken, m.DateTaken))
        AND (m.OriginalSizeKB >= ISNULL(@MinFileSize, m.OriginalSizeKB))
        AND (m.OriginalSizeKB <= ISNULL(@MaxFileSize, m.OriginalSizeKB))
        AND((m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@ImageType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@AudioType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@VideoType, 0))
        OR (m.FKMediaObjectTypeId = ISNULL(@OtherType, 0)))

and UPPER(md.Description) = 'KEYWORDS'
        and exists (
                SELECT *
                FROM    dbo.fnSplit(Replace(md.Value, '''', ''''''), ',') split
                WHERE   split.item in 
                (SELECT * from dbo.fnSplit(Replace(@Keywords, '''', ''''''), ','))
        )
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about instead of  doing the intersect, try this out in your inner queries : @Keyword is null or .....

```
        and ( @Keywords is null or  (UPPER(md.Description) = 'KEYWORDS'
        and exists (
                SELECT *
                FROM    dbo.fnSplit(Replace(md.Value, '''', ''''''), ',') split
                WHERE   split.item in 
                (SELECT * from dbo.fnSplit(Replace(@Keywords, '''', ''''''), ','))
           )
          )
         )
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, it's not working with the code as is, but I'll keep tweaking see if I can make it work